# Java Program that lets user guess 3 letters in order to guess a name?

Tags: java, eclipse

I need some help with how to approach a java program that lets a user enter 3 different letters separately and tells them if they are in a set word or not, and if so at what index. This is for intro so it should most likely be a piece of cake for you experts. We have no notes on this section so im really stumped. All we know how to do is basic strings. So far i have.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class guessletter {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String name = "carson";
            int namelength = name.length();
            System.out.println("The name is "+namelength+" charecters long");
            System.out.println("Please enter a letter to guess?");
            String letter1 = scan.nextLine();   
            System.out.println("Please enter a letter to guess?");
            String letter2 = scan.nextLine();   
            System.out.println("Please enter a letter to guess?");
            String letter3 = scan.nextLine();   
        }   
    }
```

Update: Forgot to mention on how the user must be able to guess the word at the end to see if they were right. I think i have it down but it says the correct name is wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class guessletter
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = "carson";
    String name2;
    int namelength = name.length();
    System.out.println("The name is "+namelength+" charecters long");

    System.out.println("Please enter a letter to guess?");
    char letter = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);  // Gets the first character in the input  
    checkLetter(name, letter);

    System.out.println("Please enter a letter to guess?");
    letter = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);  
    checkLetter(name, letter); 

    System.out.println("Please enter a letter to guess?");
    letter = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);   
    checkLetter(name, letter);
    System.out.println("Please guess what the name is.");
    name2= scan.nextLine();
    if (name2 == name)
         System.out.println("Yes that is the name");
    else
         System.out.println("Nope, that is not the name");
    System.out.println("The name is "+name+"");

    }   

    public static void checkLetter(String name, char letter)
    {
    int indexOfLetter = name.indexOf(letter);
    if (indexOfLetter == -1)
        System.out.println("That letter isn't found in the name");
    else
        System.out.println("That Letter is in name. It is located at index " + (indexOfLetter+1));
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework questions should include at least an attempt to solve the problem in question.

Answer (score 2):

**Pay attention** that the user **will not necessarily enter just one letter.** You should take this into consideration and test only the first character of the input string.

One possible approach is as follows:

In this code, you scan only the first character from every inputed string (as needed) with `.charAt(0)` and then test if it is in the string using the `.indexOf(letter)` method on the `name` variable as needed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class guessletter
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = "carson";
    int namelength = name.length();
    System.out.println("The name is "+namelength+" charecters long");

    System.out.println("Please enter a letter to guess?");
    char letter = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);  // Gets the first character in the input  
    checkLetter(name, letter);

    System.out.println("Please enter a letter to guess?");
    letter = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);  
    checkLetter(name, letter); 

    System.out.println("Please enter a letter to guess?");
    letter = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);   
    checkLetter(name, letter);

    }   

    public static void checkLetter(String name, char letter)
    {
    int indexOfLetter = name.indexOf(letter);
    if (indexOfLetter == -1)
        System.out.prinln("Letter is not in name");
    else
        System.out.println("Letter is in name! index is " + (indexOfLetter+1));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the method **String#indexOf**, if the given char is not in the word, the method return -1.

```
   String name = "carson";
   System.out.println(name.indexOf("a"));
   System.out.println(name.indexOf("z"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the work for you,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class guess
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = "carson";
        int namelength = name.length();
        int l=3;
        String letter;
        System.out.println("The name is "+namelength+" charecters long");
        while(l-->0){
        System.out.println("Please enter a letter to guess?");
         letter= scan.nextLine(); 
         if(name.indexOf(letter)!=-1){
            System.out.println("Letter found at position "+(name.indexOf(letter)+1));
         }else{
            System.out.println("Letter not found");
         }
        }

    }    

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use .contains for Strings

```
if(name.contains("a")){
//code
}
```